# Calibrate R model object in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, calibration

I have an XGBoost model developed in R that I want to calibrate in Python.

It is stored as a `xgb.model` file.
I have successfully loaded this in Python using the following lines of code.

```
model = xgboost.Booster(model_file="path_to_xgb.model")
```

I am using the following code to generate a calibrator object but upon trying to fit the calibrator i get a runtime error.

```
calibrator = CalibratedClassifierCV(model, cv = 'prefit', method = 'sigmoid')
calibrator.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain)
```

The error i see is

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py", line 297, in _preproc
raise RuntimeError('classifier has no decision_function or '
RuntimeError: classifier has no decision_function or predict_proba method.
```

I am taken care of the disjoint nature of the data sets but will appreciate any help I can get on how to proceed on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap your XGBoost `Booster` object into a Scikit-Learn compatible [`xgboost.XGBClassifier`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier) object first.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the tip. Do you have any suggestions on how i can do that?